# Why compiler is accepting a non-final variable in inner class?

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

I am creating a MediaPlayer with seekbar.Here, *mp* is a MediaPlayer object and *seeker* is a seekbar object created in the MainActivity class.

My understanding is that only final members are accessible to the anonymous inner class.Then **how does runnable access those objects**(mp and seeker).

```
     h = new Handler();  // create a handler for the MainActivity

 //create a runnable activity to change the progress of seekbar in MainThread for every 1 sec
   Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mp != null) {
                seeker.setProgress(mp.getCurrentPosition() / 1000);
            }
           h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
   };

    this.runOnUiThread(r);
```

Note : The code works perfectly.Thanks for help.

Comment: @user3215142 ... and there was a rule that such variables had to be `final`, which is what the question is actually about. Your unsourced claim that the 'recommended way is to make your runnables static' needs substantiation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens, cause there is something called **effectively final**.

**[jls-8.1.3:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)**

> Any local variable, formal parameter, or exception parameter used but not declared in an inner class must either be declared final or be effectively final (§4.12.4), or a compile-time error occurs where the use is attempted.

**[jls-4.12.4:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)**

> If a variable is effectively final, adding the final modifier to its declaration will not introduce any compile-time errors. Conversely, a local variable or parameter that is declared final in a valid program becomes effectively final if the final modifier is removed.

When variable is only set once and it is used in a inner class, the compiler turn the modifier of variable to `final`.

Consider this code **Tests.java:**

```
public class Tests  {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
       String value = "Hello";

       Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               System.out.println(value);
           }
       };
   }
}
```

The code above, when compiled, will produce this code bellow. Can you see that compiler change the modifier of `value` to final?

**Tests.class (decoded):**

```
public class Tests {
    public Tests() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        final String value = "Hello";
        Runnable var10000 = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

But, if you change the value of variable (see code bellow), it won't be compiled, because the compiler know that it is not a effectively final variable:

```
public class Tests  {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
       String value = "Hello";
       value = "world";

       Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               System.out.println(value);
           }
       };
   }
}
```